# How do I use JMESPath to query values in a list?

Tags: jmespath

Given the following structure,

```
{
    "Imports": [
        "network-secgrp", 
        "bastion", 
        "network-nacl"
    ]
}
```

How do I get JMESPath to only output the values that start with `network`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With

```
Imports[?starts_with(@, `network`)]
```

You will have

```
[
  "network-secgrp",
  "network-nacl"
]
```

I recommend you to use this editor http://jmespath.org/

It is a great playground :)

Comment: this doesn't seem to work for me on the CLI. Any idea why?
`echo '{
    "Imports": [
        "network-secgrp", 
        "bastion", 
        "network-nacl"
    ]
}' | jp 'Imports[?starts_with(@, \`n\`)]'
`